# Opposite of os.path.commonprefix

Tags: python, path

What's the opposite of os.path.commonprefix? I have two paths and I want the non-overlapping path, e.g.:

```
>>> p1 = '/Users/foo/something'
>>> p2 = '/Users/foo/something/else/etc'
>>> print somefunction([p1, p2])
'/else/etc'
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
>>> p1 = '/Users/foo/something'
>>> p2 = '/Users/foo/something/else/etc'
>>> os.path.relpath(p2, start=p1)
'else/etc'
```

The correct answer is `'else/etc'` and not `'/else/etc'`.

If you are in p1 and type `cd /else/etc` you wouldn't land in p2, but somewhere else.

`os.path.join(p1, 'else/etc')` gives you p2 again.

Comment: Oh great! I went over and over the docs for os.path and missed this (must be blind). Thanks!